# session variables SOMETIMES not passing?

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a site that i am using session variables.  up until last Wednesday this was working fine but now is sporadically working.  Sometimes I can retreive the session vars and sometimes i cant.  What could be going on and how can i trouble shoot this with my hosting company if its a server issue?

I have this page for testing setting sessions which works all the time no problem and session cookie domain is always blank:

```
<?
session_start();

$_SESSION['ID'] = "112233";
$_SESSION['token'] = "mytoken";

print "Created Session ID: ".$_SESSION['ID']."<br>";
print "Created Session Token: ".$_SESSION['token']."<br>";

print "Session Cookie Domain If Set: ".ini_get('session.cookie_domain')."<br><br>";

?>
<a href="info2.php">Click To See If Sessions Are Passing</a>
```

Then i click through to this page to see if sessions are passing or not.  This is the page that sometimes shows the sessions i set in the above code and sometimes doesnt.  session cookie domain has always been blank on this page as well:

```
<?
session_start();

print "Passed Session ID: ".$_SESSION['ID']."<br>";
print "Passed Session Token: ".$_SESSION['token']."<br>";

print "Session Cookie Domain If Set: ".ini_get('session.cookie_domain')."<br><br>";

?>
If session ID doesnt say "112233" and session token doesnt say "mytoken" then there is a problem.<br /><br />
<a href="info.php">Go Back To Set Session Variables</a>
```

These two pages are on HTTPS i dont know if that info is relevent or not but i thought i would mention it. I dont think it browser related cause when its not working i have loaded these pages in windows ie 8 and google chrome and on a mac safari, firefox and google chrome with the same results.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Is there anything in phpinfo() i could look at when things are working or not working that may help resolve this? This is driving me nuts because like i said it works sometimes and sometimes it doesnt.

Comment: Are you switching protocols (http:// to https://  or vice versa)?

Comment: on the real site that i created it can go between http and https but in this scenario with the two example pages i created for testing its always https

Comment: Don't blame the session. Blame the lack of a session cookie, causing a new session to be created. Check that the session cookie's value isn't changing between requests. If it is, you're getting a new blank session.

Comment: how do i check session cookies value?

Comment: @user520300: it is usually kept under the name "PHPSESSID" in the cookies your site is setting. You can check it in your browser content, or just output your $_COOKIE data with var_dump($_COOKIE);.

Comment: the PHPSESSID is the same on both pages based in the var_dump($_COOKIE); info just spoaradically the session set on the one page are empty on the next when trying to retreive them

Comment: Does anyone who has read this and or commented think this could be an issue with the hosting company and maybe php configuration that would cause this to work sometimes and sometimes not?  Im sure im passing sessions correctly as i have done this many times before on other servers with no issues.  Its just weird that it works sometimes and not others.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This was a server error somewhere.  The hosting provider had to change something.  After that everthing worked fine.

Thanks for all the help and input